# Unable to extract the required information from tcpdump results

Tags: http, tcpdump

New to networking tools, I was just trying to use tcpdump to do basic analysis. On issuing the following command:

```
tcpdump -X -n -i wlan0 -s 0 port 80
```

and browsing the net (accessed stackoverflow.com and performed a search) using the browser, I was expecting to see the URL and the search string in the output generated, but somehow it wasn't there.

Am I missing something...

Comment: [Since last year SO/Stack uses HTTPS](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/) so the data sent by your browser and returned to it is **encrypted and unreadable** in a capture. Most serious websites have switched to HTTPS over roughly the past 5 years, partly in response to the public concern resulting from Snowden's revelation of large-scale monitoring of Internet traffic. This is not a programming Q and offtopic in SO; it is ontopic and has been asked many times on security.SX and to a lesser extent webmasters.SX.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, will switch to SX for such questions.